# Ajax doesn't render SelectManyBox correctly, its rendered after page referesh

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to render a `h:selectManyBoxList` upon a selectOneMenu choice, so the data of the selectManyBox comes when user selects a item from selectOneMenu

here is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{exportManager.htmlExportSelected}">
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control" immediate="true" 
                                            value="#{exportManager.selectedTemplateObjectTypeId}"
                                            required="true">
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{templateManager.templateDetails}"
                                                var="oneDetail"
                                                itemLabel="#{oneDetail.childObjectType.title}"
                                                itemValue="#{oneDetail.childObjectType.objectTypeId}" />
                                            <f:ajax event="change" render="multi-select-property" ></f:ajax>
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label></label>
                        </div>

                                    <div align="right" class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6" align="right">
                                                <b><label class="control-label">#{uiLabelManager.nonSelected}</label></b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                                                <b><label class="control-label">#{uiLabelManager.selected}</label></b>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>

                                    <div align="right" class="form-group"  >
                                        <h:panelGroup id="many-list-box" rendered="#{not empty exportManager.selectedObjects}">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="float:left"> 
                                            <h:selectManyListbox id="multi-select-property"
                                                value="#{exportManager.selectedObjects}"
                                                styleClass="form-control multi-select" immediate="true"
                                                style="width:250px;height:250px">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{exportManager.loadObjectNodes()}"
                                                    var="oneDetail" itemLabel="#{oneDetail.title}"
                                                    itemValue="#{oneDetail.objectId}" />
                                                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" execute="@this" partialSubmit="true"
                                                update=":content-form:multi-select-property"
                                                    render="@form"></p:ajax>
                                            </h:selectManyListbox>

                                            <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="form-control" style="width:250px"
                                                value="#{exportManager.selectedObjects}" required="true">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{exportManager.selectedObjects}" />
                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </div>
                                </h:panelGroup>
```

here is a screen shot before I select a item from `selectOneMenu`

[image: before item selection]

here is the screen shot after I select a item from `selectOneMenu`

[image: after item selection]

as you can see the one newly rendered grayed-out box is the one with new data and the correctly render `selectManyBox` was also there below,so when I referesh page this happens, which you can see in image:

[image: after page referesh <code>selectManyBox</code> is rendered correctly]

I can't find a way to fix this, only page refresh fixes this so I have to add

```
onchange="submit()"
```

in the `selectOneMenu` this reloads whole page which is not user friendly and time consuming a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using a CSS or JS library to style your `<h:selectManyListbox...` which is rewriting the element in the DOM. You'll need to execute the necessary JS to stylize the `<h:selectManyListbox...` after the DOM has been updated with the re-rendered component from the AJAX call.

You may be able to leverage the `oncomplete` attribute of PrimeFaces `<p:ajax/>` to accomplish this.